# Writing a for loop function that returns boolean values

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input vector, v, and returns a vector of the same length whose elements are boolean values indicating whether or not the corresponding element of the input vector indicates the variable homelessness. The function should loop over elements of
v and uses the homeless vector to flag those elements of v that indicate the arrestee is homeless

I keep getting an error saying "object 'n' not found"

I've tried changing the ith variable to flag_homeless to no success.

```
flag_homeless <- function(v) 
    n <- length(v)
        homeless <- rep(FALSE, n)
            for (i in 1:n) {
                    if (v[i] == "No Permanent Address")  {
                        homeless[i] <- TRUE }
        }
        return(homeless)
```

Comment: I don’t think you need a function, based on your description you can probably achieve this with `grepl()`. If you provide example data we can provide more specific help

Answer (score 0):

You could use another pair of braces for your `function` call. It's difficult to understand the scope of `flag_homeless` otherwise.

```
flag_homeless <- function(v) {
    n <- length(v)
    homeless <- rep(FALSE, n)
    for (i in 1:n) {
         if (v[i] == "No Permanent Address")  {
             homeless[i] <- TRUE }
    }
    return(homeless)
}
```

Comment: The missing bracket was the issue. Silly mistake! Thank you for the reply!

Comment: If this is correct, you can check the mark next to this answer as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because R is vectorized, you usually don't need to use an explicit loop.  Here is a toy example with a binary A/B test analogous to your requirement:

```
v <- sample(c('A', 'B'), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))
test <- v == 'B'
sum(test)
[1] 71
```

You would use "No Permanent Address" as your B test.